# Action on self created View

Tags: ember.js

If I've a simple template with a Button which has an Action, and create a ember View using this template, how can I let the action target the function on teh View.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Krutius/DxsXz/

**Handlebars / HTML**:

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action go}}>Suchen</button>
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(function() {
    App = Em.Application.create({
        rootElement: "#content"
    });

    Em.View.create({
        templateName: 'test',
        go: function() {
            alert: "go";
        }
    }).append("#main");
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `append` call: `Ember.View#append` does not take any arguments, see the [code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/541d085ae039a190d24213d1476de53029355bf9/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1191-1204).

I don't know what the final application / html should look like, so there are several answers how you could solve your problem. The simplest would be to inline the button into a template for the application, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/vY9PE/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action go}}>Suchen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```html
App = Em.Application.create({});

Em.View.create({
    templateName: 'test',
    go: function(evt) {
        console.log('go', evt);
    }
}).append();​
```

---

Ember.js **IS** able to insert an element at a specific position though, but this should only be necessary for an applications' main view. So you could use `Ember.View#appendTo(target)`. But again, this should only be used in rare cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate why `appendTo(target)` should be rarely used?

Comment: It's stated in the docs: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/541d085ae039a190d24213d1476de53029355bf9/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1122-1126